# Remove cell highlighting when dismissing navigation destination

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm building a simple searchable list in SwiftUI.

```
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var productFinder = ProductFinder.init()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Søg...", text: $productFinder.searchQuery)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.horizontal, 18)
                List(productFinder.filteredProducts) { product in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ProductView(product: product),
                        label: { ProductCell(product: product) }
                    )
                }
            .navigationBarTitle("Søg efter produkt")
        }
    }
}
```

When tapping a cell, the DestinationView (`ProductView`) gets pushed as expected and the cell gets highlighted. But after dismissing the DestinationView, the cell keeps it's highlighted state, until I press another cell.

[image: cell keeps highligted]

I would expect the highlighting to disappear when the cell gets dismissed.

I tried:

- set `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` on `NavigationLink` and `ProductCell` -> No effect
- set `tag` and `selection` parameters on `NavigationLink` -> No effect
- set `UITableView.appearance().allowsSelection = false` and `UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none` in `SearchView`'s `init` -> No effect
- delete derived data, clean project and re-build -> No effect

Comment: you must deselect it after you navigate, chek it out: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663562